# Cannot install original application and its test variant

Tags: android, installation

For doing some tests, I need to install test version of the existing application. I've renamed my app from `AndroidTimer` to `AndroidTestTimer`, revised manifest, but only one of these applications can be installed on the device. After uninstalling, any of them can be installed. However,, when I try to install the second one, device is treating it as update to existing application, and cannot install. Why so? These applications have now different names.
Here is two manifest files.

For AndroidTimer:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="spectorsky.timer">
>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>     <uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
>
>     <!-- <uses-permission     android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/> -->
>
>     <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/video_television"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
>     <activity
>         android:name=".AdvancedActivity"
>         android:label="@string/advancedMenu"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
>
>     </activity>
>
>     <receiver android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver" />
>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
>         <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

For AndroidTestTimer:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="spectorsky.testTimer">
>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
>
>     <!-- <uses-permission     android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/> -->
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:icon="@drawable/video_television"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:supportsRtl="true"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
>
>         <receiver android:name=".MyTestAlarmReceiver" />
>
>         <activity
>             android:name=".TestAdvancedActivity"
>             android:label="@string/app_name"
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
>             <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                 <category     android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             </intent-filter>
>
>         </activity>
>     </application>
> ```

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: Those would appear to be directory names, or possibly string resource values. Neither have anything to do with the application ID/package name of the app.

Comment: Have you changed the package name ?

Comment: Application name change won't work,you need to change your package name. for ex : ** package="com.androidTestTimer" and package="com.AndroidTimer **

Comment: Thanks everybody for quick replies. I've changed package name from `spectorsky.timer` to `spectorsky.testTimer`. Sorry, but the package name disappeared from code (because of lacking of 4 spaces), now it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting almost everything from the test project, I've found the reason why this test app was treated as update to original. In the `build.grandle` of module there is such a part:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "spectorsky.test"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

It was blame of `applicationId`: the value was the same as in original application. It was strange because I renamed the app long ago, but `applicationId` was set to rather old value, from the very beginning, when the name of original application contained 'test'.

Many thanks to everybodies who tried to help. A special thanks to  CommonsWare who has mentioned `applicationId` in his comment.